# join 2 queries SQL + ColdFusion

Tags: sql, join, coldfusion

Got two queries, and can't make them work properly, their end product gives the repeated items, here is the queries:

**1st Query**

```
<cfquery name="get_partner_all" datasource="#dsn#">
    SELECT  
        C.COMPANY_ID,
        C.FULLNAME,
        CP.MOBILTEL,
        CP.MOBIL_CODE, 
        CP.IMCAT_ID,
        CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_TEL, 
        CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_TELCODE,
        CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_TEL_EXT,
        CP.MISSION, 
        CP.DEPARTMENT, 
        CP.TITLE,
        CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_SURNAME, 
        CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_NAME, 
        CP.PARTNER_ID, 
        CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_EMAIL, 
        CP.HOMEPAGE, 
        CP.COUNTY,
        CP.COUNTRY,
        CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_ADDRESS, 
        CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_FAX,
        CP.RECORD_DATE,
        CP.MEMBER_CODE,
        CC.COMPANYCAT
        <cfif isdefined('attributes.report_sort') and attributes.report_sort is 2>
        ,CCD.SITE_DOMAIN
        </cfif>
    FROM
        COMPANY_PARTNER CP,
        COMPANY C,
        COMPANY_CAT CC
        <cfif isdefined('attributes.report_sort') and attributes.report_sort is 2>
        ,COMPANY_CONSUMER_DOMAINS CCD
        </cfif>
    WHERE
        C.COMPANY_ID = CP.COMPANY_ID
        AND C.COMPANYCAT_ID = CC.COMPANYCAT_ID      
    <cfif isDefined('attributes.search_status') and len(attributes.search_status)> 
        AND CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_STATUS = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#attributes.search_status#">
    </cfif>
    <cfelseif isDefined("attributes.comp_cat") and len(attributes.comp_cat)>
        AND C.COMPANYCAT_ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#attributes.comp_cat#">
    </cfif>
    <cfif isdefined('attributes.report_sort') and attributes.report_sort is 2>
        AND CP.PARTNER_ID = CCD.PARTNER_ID
        AND CCD.SITE_DOMAIN = 'www.projedepo.com'
    </cfif>
</cfquery>
```

**2nd Query:**

```
<cfquery name="get_money" datasource="#dsn2#">
    SELECT BAKIYE,BORC,ALACAK FROM COMPANY_REMAINDER_MONEY WHERE COMPANY_ID = #company_id#
</cfquery>
```

when i try to define the for example C.COMPANY_ID=CRM.COMPANY_ID it shows some repeated items, i know that i should use smth like JOIN and other stuff, but can't understand how to do it :) need help, and thank you all for help!

**here's the joined query, still repeated variables:**

```
<cfquery name="get_partner_all" datasource="#dsn#">
    SELECT DISTINCT
        C.COMPANY_ID,
        C.FULLNAME,
        CP.MOBILTEL,
        CP.MOBIL_CODE, 
        CP.IMCAT_ID,
        CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_TEL, 
        CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_TELCODE,
        CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_TEL_EXT,
        CP.MISSION, 
        CP.DEPARTMENT, 
        CP.TITLE,
        CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_SURNAME, 
        CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_NAME, 
        CP.PARTNER_ID, 
        CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_EMAIL, 
        CP.HOMEPAGE, 
        CP.COUNTY,
        CP.COUNTRY,
        CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_ADDRESS, 
        CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_FAX,
        CP.RECORD_DATE,
        CP.MEMBER_CODE,
        CC.COMPANYCAT,
        CRM.*
        <cfif isdefined('attributes.report_sort') and attributes.report_sort is 2>
        ,CCD.SITE_DOMAIN
        </cfif>
    FROM
        COMPANY_PARTNER CP,
        COMPANY C,
        COMPANY_CAT CC,
        #dsn2_alias#.COMPANY_REMAINDER_MONEY CRM
        <cfif isdefined('attributes.report_sort') and attributes.report_sort is 2>
        ,COMPANY_CONSUMER_DOMAINS CCD
        </cfif>
    WHERE
        C.COMPANY_ID = CP.COMPANY_ID
        AND C.COMPANYCAT_ID = CC.COMPANYCAT_ID
        AND C.COMPANY_ID=CRM.COMPANY_ID 
    <cfif isDefined('attributes.search_status') and len(attributes.search_status)> 
        AND CP.COMPANY_PARTNER_STATUS = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#attributes.search_status#">
    </cfif>     
    <cfif isDefined("attributes.cpid") and len(attributes.cpid)>
        AND C.COMPANY_ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#attributes.cpid#">
    <cfelseif isDefined("attributes.comp_cat") and len(attributes.comp_cat)>
        AND C.COMPANYCAT_ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#attributes.comp_cat#">
    </cfif>
    <cfif isdefined('attributes.report_sort') and attributes.report_sort is 2>
        AND CP.PARTNER_ID = CCD.PARTNER_ID
        AND CCD.SITE_DOMAIN = 'www.projedepo.com'
    </cfif>
</cfquery>
```

Comment: If `COMPANY_REMAINDER_MONEY` contains multiple records per companyID you will need to use some sort of aggregate. Otherwise companies will be displayed once for each record in `COMPANY_REMAINDER_MONEY` because that is what the sql is requesting.

Comment: So are there multiple records? If yes, which one do you want to return (latest, greatest, ..)?

Comment: @Leigh what do you mean by latest and greatest etc..? :) sorry im a newbie in a sql and coldfusion, just have multiple variables instead of one, and can't uderstand how to avoid it

Comment: What is the relation between tables `COMPANY` and `COMPANY_PARTNER` ? One-to-many ?

Comment: And what is the relation between tables `COMPANY` and `COMPANY_CONSUMER_DOMAINS` ? Again one-to-many ?

Comment: @ypercube yes, this is way up, as i remember u solved the domains issue before, this can be familiar to you :)

Comment: If both answers are yes, then that's the cause of data appearing multiple times.

Comment: @ypercube is there anyway to avoid it?

Comment: The query is not wrong, it just shows all (valid) combinations of COMPANY_PARTNERs and COMPANY_CONSUMER_DOMAINS.

Comment: yes i got it :) so there is no way to combine them?

Comment: @ypercube actually i solved this problem, by defining the new query inside the output of this query, but for now i need to make an ORDER BY for CRM, and i can't do it because it is outside the main query, that is the real purpose for combining them :)

Comment: @user775917 - It sounds like you are now running queries within a loop? That is generally *very* inefficient. Almost certain there is an alternative. But you have not given us much to go on ... ;) Help us out. Post some sample data and a summary of the relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query is not wrong, it just shows all (valid) combinations of COMPANY_PARTNERs and COMPANY_CONSUMER_DOMAINS. if you want that, you can add an `ORDER BY` in the end:

```
ORDER BY C.COMPANY_ID,
         CP.PARTNER_ID,
         CRM.DOMAINID          --- some field in table CRM
```

or

```
ORDER BY C.COMPANY_ID,
         CRM.DOMAINID          --- some field in table CRM
         CP.PARTNER_ID,
```

or whichever other ordering you like, say:

```
ORDER BY C.COMPANY_NAME
         C.COMPANY_ID,
         CP.COUNTRY,
         CP.COUNTY,
         CP.TITLE,
         CP.PARTNER_ID,
```

---

I see two more ways where this query can show (other possibly interesting) data:

**1** Change (in the SELECT list)  `CRM.*` into   `Count(*) AS ConsumerDomainsCount`

and add a `GROUP BY CP.COMPANY_ID, CP.PARTNER_ID` at the end.

**2** Mirror operation, `GROUP BY CRM.COMPANY_ID, CRM.DOMAINID` and change the SELECT list by removing any `CP.*` and keep only `Count(*) AS PartnersCount`

---

If you use `GROUP BY`, you could also use other aggregate functions, like `SUM()`, `AVG()`, `MIN()`, `MAX()` if you have fields that can be added (numer fields) or compared (like dates).

Answer (score -1):

Is this as simple as using the `DISTINCT` keyword?

```
<cfquery name="get_money" datasource="#dsn2#">
    SELECT DISTINCT COL1, COL2 ... FROM ...
</cfquery>
```

Also - you should use `<cfqueryparam />` to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: didn't help.. p.s. i didnt minus your answer :)